# iphone app works locally but not when its downloaded from the app store

Tags: cordova, cordova-3, cordova-plugins

Hi my iphone app that i have developed in xcode uses the cordova / phonegap library

i have been able to successfully build and upload 3-4 versions of my app and then when i download to my phone from the app store the app works as expected

the app loads and builds successfully when i attached my iphone also the builds complete when i validate through the itunes connect process to upload to the app store, just when i download the app from the app store and install it thats when the splash screen opens ands suddenly closes 1 second later

i have asked apple dev team and they claim as its developed in a third party platform they cannot assist despite the app passing all validation processes of xcode / itunes connect and ultimately released on the app store itself

Answer (score 0):

Check the functionality you added by running the app in xcode and check the log for errors.

Without posting specific error messages or your new code, there is little we can do to help.